# How to replace text in textarea with a mat-chip?

Tags: angular, angular-material, textarea

In my case I have a textarea where the user can create a template for an email with variables.
A valid variable name would be '$TIMESTAMP$'. The user can switch the input between text- and visual-mode. In the visual-mode all variables should be replaced with a mat-chip for better visualization but the text should still be editable.

Is there a way to solve my problem?

PS: If possible I just want to use material components not other external libraries.

Edit:
[image]

Comment: use chips with input from angular material.

Comment: I can't use chips with inputs because the goal is that it is a mixture of text and chips. I have added a screenshot for better understanding what I mean.

Comment: You can do it with a normal div, style it as you want with border-radius 25% so that left and right sides of the div become the same as the mat-chip and set color and styles like padding etc...  for each div and bind the css to div through class , and then add to div attribute contenteditable="true"

Comment: Did you get solution to your  question?

Comment: any update on this please ?